# Cypher Query where target reverse matches all relationship requirements

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am using Neo4j Community 3.4.1.

I have a graph that looks like:
[Data Model Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrgZP.png)

The green nodes are listings.

The top listing is  *Listing One* and the bottom one *Listing Two*

The top feature is *Fireplace* and the bottom feature is *Parking*

I am looking for a Cypher query that starts at a specific listing and finds all the SavedSearches that meet **all** the conditions for that SavedSearch.

For instance, **Listing Two** would fulfill the above `SavedSearch` because it has relationships with both of the SavedSearch's conditions.

However, **Listing One** would not meet the criteria, because the listing only meets one of the SavedSearches conditions.

I have the following query, which starts on a listing and matches any saved search that has a direct path, but the search does not check that all of the paths from the Saved Search connect back. So, the following query will return the SavedSearch for BOTH Listing One and Listing Two:

```
MATCH (l:Listing {list_id: 'one'})
MATCH (l)-[:ATTRIBUTE]
      ->(:Value {field: 'features', value: 'Fireplace'})
      <-[:CONDITION]
      -(s:SavedSearch)
RETURN s
```

Is there a way to match that SavedSearch and then trace the searches paths back to see if all the CONDITION paths lead back to the same listing?

I would like to do this as a straight Cypher Query, but am willing to do a custom procedure and use the Java API if that is easier and vastly more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution using [collect()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) and [all()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-all) functions:

```
match (:Listing {list_id :'one'})-[:ATTRIBUTE]->(attr:Value {field: 'features', value: 'Fireplace'})
with collect(attr) as attrs
match (s:SavedSearch)
where all (attr in attrs where (s)-[:CONDITION]->(attr))
return s
```

I'm storing all attributes into a collection called `attrs`. Then matching all `SavedSearch`es that are connected to each `attr`.